# Why there is a EE.Sx question on this site?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I was looking for a rail-to-rail OPAMP model for Qucs, in order to help the OP of [this question](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CD4QFjAA&url=https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25834/op-amp-circuit-not-behaving-as-desired&ei=XGw6T-KzLpGc8gPomrDrCg&usg=AFQjCNFYMJPhZu8Gdw56Xyip3cgK2EDbHQ&sig2=gFgt1kBi1QrQ71ovKTTC0g)...and one of the links that Google gives is [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CGcQFjAG&url=http://b.vniup.com/index.php/electronic/op-amp-circuit-not-behaving-as-desired.html&ei=XGw6T-KzLpGc8gPomrDrCg&usg=AFQjCNEdK3U7pE8J5s0cJCOj8-C0Gp1mBA&sig2=WpMf7ghDGRW2N_5FsyKcKQ): it seems to be the copy of that question, with figures and comments embedded, but without author names and/or link/reference to this site.

Is this a copy-paste, or there is something that I don't get?

I don't even know how to tag, since I don't know what this is...

Answer (score 3):

All the content you publish on this site is under a [Creative Commons Wiki (attribution required) license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (which is described in further detail [on the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)).  To make this effective (and reduce the harmful effects of scrapers), Stack Exchange publishes a [data dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) every few months.

You can use this data dump to backup your contributions, to do textual analysis, or to republish it in a different format.  In this case, the linked site republished it in a Wordpress blog format with comments and ads.

To republish the content legally, 'attribution' means:

> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)
>
> By “directly”, I mean each hyperlink must point directly to our domain in standard HTML visible even with JavaScript disabled, and not use a tinyurl or any other form of obfuscation or redirection. Furthermore, the links must not be nofollowed.

The linked site does not properly attribute the content.  This isn't new, it's been tried many other times by black-hat SEO companies and people trying to make a quick buck: There's lots of hyperlinked, quality, hand-crafted content.

This is described further at [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers), and there's a listing of illegal clones at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106824/146495).  This listing includes the `vniup.com` domain which your link points to:

> #### bicycles.vniup.com and www.vniup.com
>
> - content on bicycles is from [Bicycles.SE] (I recognized it) and content on www sure looks like it's from other SE sites
> - In addition, there is scraped content from:
>
>   - [CSTheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://vniup.com/index.php/category/computer-science/`)
>   - [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/english-learning`)
>   - [Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/electronic`)
>   - [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/gamer`)
>   - [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/geographic-information-system`)
>   - [Home Improvement/DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/house-improvement`)
>   - [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/physics`)
>   - [Sharepoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/sharepoint`)
>   - [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/text-and-document`)
>   - [AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/) (see `http://vniup.com/index.php/category/ubuntu`)
>   - [AskDifferent.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (though it seems to be only [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35196/jailbroken-iphone-stuck-on-boot-screen/35199#35199) repeated over and over...)
> - The categories on vniup.com itself seem to be scraping some of the larger Ubuntu tag feeds.
> - Shows names of answerers, but not askers. There is no further attribution to SE or any indication that the site is not providing original content.

I added the b.vniup.com subdomain to that list.

Additional things you can do are to [block that site from your Google results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210386) and to [report a scraper page](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dGM4TXhIOFd3c1hZR2NHUDN1NmllU0E6MQ&ndplr=1).  Those only affect the Google ranking of the site, they don't actually bring any damages - but remember that delisting from Google is about as bad as it gets for a scraper!

Finally, if the linked site ranks higher than electronics.stackexchange.com for some query in Google, please [post it here on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here) so that the Stack Exchange team can figure out what they're doing to get the extra Google juice and make our site rank higher than the scraper.